# Can't install driver for mysql for tarantool

Tags: mysql, tarantool

Use tarantool version:Tarantool 1.6.8-586-g504e151
Installed from epel.
I want install driver for mysql, try this instruction on github: https://github.com/tarantool/mysql

1. `git clone mysql.git tarantool-mysql` - OK
2. `cd tarantool-mysql` -OK
3. `cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebugInfo` - FAIL ON THIS STEP

> ```
> cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebugInfo
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- INCLUDE_DIR TARANTOOL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
> -- PREFIX 
> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108
> ```
>
> (message):
>         Could NOT find TARANTOOL (missing: TARANTOOL_INCLUDE_DIR)
>       Call Stack (most recent call first):
>         /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>         cmake/FindTarantool.cmake:29 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
>         CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)

How i can specify `TARANTOOL dir`?

I also tried to install via luarocks but it was also unsuccessful:

`luarocks install`

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tarantool/mysql/master/mysql-scm-1.rockspec --local
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tarantool/mysql/master/mysql-scm-1.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
```

> Error: Could not find expected file mysql/mysql.h, or mysql/mysql.h for MYSQL -- you may have to install MYSQL in your system and/or pass MYSQL_DIR or MYSQL_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install mysql MYSQL_DIR=/usr/local

P.P.S.

```
yum install libmysqlclient-dev tarantool-dev
467 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
No package libmysqlclient-dev available.
No package tarantool-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1):

1. libmysqlclient-dev is the appropriate name on Ubuntu, but since you mention epel I'll guess you might want to try install mysql-devel instead. (Different distros, different naming conventions.)
2. On my machine "cmake . -DMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR=mysql-include-directory" seems to work but is undocumented. However, if you install to the default directory, you shouldn't need that. Sometimes "mysql_config --include" will tell you where mysql.h is.
3. The Tarantool manual suggests that first you should install tarantool-dev on Ubuntu
   http://tarantool.org/doc/book/app/d-plugins.html
   but again I'm guessing you want a more epel-friendly package like this one:
   https://pkgs.org/centos-7/epel-x86_64/tarantool-devel-1.6.8.530-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html
   -- you'll notice that it has files for "/usr/include/tarantool".